# How to optimize component rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to optimize component rendering?

I have routes, depending on which the content of the sidebar changes, but there are places where the route is different, *and the content of the sidebar does not change, how to make sure that in this case the sidebar does not **re-render**?*

```
  {
    path: '/users',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: () => <SidebarComponents.Users/>, // 1
    main: () => <Modules.Users/>,
  },
  {
    path: '/users/:id/settings',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: () => <SidebarComponents.Users/>, // 2
    main: () => <Modules.UsersSettings/>,
  },
  {
    path: '/users/:id',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: () => <SidebarComponents.SelectedUser/>,
    main: () => <Modules.SelectedUser/>,
  },

{routes.map((route, idx) => (
     <Route key={idx} path={route.path} exact={route.exact}>
       <Wrapper>
         <Sidebar component={<route.sidebar />} /> // Now every time the route changes, the sidebar is re-rendered
           <>
             <Modules.Header />
             <Breadcrumbs />
             <route.main />
           </>
      </Wrapper>
     </Route>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code and understanding the issue correctly I believe this rerendering is caused by using an anonymous function to render the sidebar component instead of passing a direct reference to a React component.

Example:

```
[
  {
    path: '/users',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: SidebarComponents.Users, // 1
    main: () => <Modules.Users/>,
  },
  {
    path: '/users/:id/settings',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: SidebarComponents.Users, // 2
    main: () => <Modules.UsersSettings/>,
  },
  {
    path: '/users/:id',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: SidebarComponents.SelectedUser,
    main: () => <Modules.SelectedUser/>,
  },
]
```

...

```
{routes.map(({ exact, path, sidebar }) => (
   <Route key={path} path={path} exact={exact}>
     <Wrapper>
       <Sidebar component={sidebar} /> // <-- pass as reference
       <>
         <Modules.Header />
         <Breadcrumbs />
         <route.main />
       </>
     </Wrapper>
   </Route>
 ))}
```

...

In `Sidebar` rename the `component` prop to `Component` and render as JSX.

```
const Sidebar = ({ ...other props ..., component: Component }) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Component />
    ...
  );
}
```